# Swift, How do I convert a String to Int without explicit conversion?

Tags: swift, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

So is there another way of conversion without it being explicit?

Comment: I am a Swift beginner myself, but I do not believe you can. More importantly though, you should not do this, it is definitely a sign you are doing something wrong. Avoid implicit and hard to spot side effects, it makes debugging difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say, this is the string

```
    var stringValue = "123"
```

You can convert it into "INT" two ways

first is

```
    let intNumber : Int = Int(stringValue)!
```

second is

```
    let anotherIntNumber : Int = (stringValue as NSString).integerValue // go with first 1 as this is more of objective-c
```

Comment: Have you tried the second method with "String", as to me it gives an error "Value of type 'String' has no member 'integerValue'"  @Keshu R.

Answer (score 0):

If you confirm `String` to `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral` you can just write this:

```
let myVar: String = 1

print(myVar)
```

Just note that you need to explicitly provide a type for `myVar` as compiler doesnt know which type it shouldd choose from.

How do we conform `String` to `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`? Something like this:

```
extension String : ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
    public init(integerLiteral value: Int) {
        self = String(value)
    }
}
```

for the other way round you can look at `ExpressibleByStringLiteral`